# Troubleshooting Firefox 22 w/ FireBug 1.73 and hopefully FirePath 0.9.7

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, firebug

This is supposedly the proper version configuration.  I need to stay w/ Firefox 22 in order to be compatible with Selenium WebDriver 2.35.  I see the complete Firebug UI but the "Inspect Element" feature doesn't work.  When I enable FirePath (which is what I am really after) the FirePath tab becomes the only accessible tab but nothing appears to work.  I presume I am in some sort of configuration hell but as far as I can tell I am using the correct versions of all the aforementioned.  FWIW - running Win7 32bit.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got Firebug 1.7 because of an issue with addons.mozilla.org and Firebug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823840).

You should get the Firebug 1.11.4, which is the last version supporting Firefox 22: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/?page=1#version-1.11.4

Florent

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks. Not sure how I got myself mislead but no matter.

Comment: Seeing a nasty side affect when FireBug and FirePath are enabled.  Navigation in the test app results in new instances instead of changing the current instance.  Suppose this needs to be posted as a new question. Disabling the add-on's returns functionality to the expected behavior.